# Why two same shape numpy transfer to different length of base64

Tags: image, numpy, opencv, base64

I have two `2d` `numpy array` with same shape. And here is a brief data distribution of these two by `np.unique` and `np.mean`.

```
[   0    1    2 ... 1352 1389 1409], [ 0 12 37]
197.67762184927983, 0.23255047582304528
```

We can see the first numpy has a much larger range of data distribution. And here is the function I use to transfer `numpy` to `base64`

```
def npy2annostr(arr):
    img = Image.fromarray(arr.astype('uint8')).convert('P')
    b = BytesIO()
    img.save(b, "PNG")
    return b64encode((b.getvalue())).decode()
```

The length of the two `base64` string are `125448, 1584`. Anyone can help me explain why? And is there a way to get two same length of `base64` string?

PS: I have also tried the python built-in `base64` method which can get two same length `base64` string. However, the `base64` is not a standard `base64` (can't get a png with it)

```
import base64 
import numpy as np
s = base64.b64encode(np_array)
```

Comment: Because what you're encoding to base64 is not the raw pixel array,  but an image encoded in PNG format, which involves compression. It doesn't make sense to expect the output to be the same size in that case. | In the second case you're directly encoding the numpy array contents to base64. Expecting to get PNG by decoding that doesn't make sense -- you'll get back you you started with, an array of bytes representing pixel values.

Comment: That's quite right @DanMašek